# Positioning "registration form" example widget in ExtJS4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

We're trying to position the "registration form" from the ExtJS4 examples (from the Sencha site: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/form/registration.html), and we can't get it to respond to center tags or any of the usual relative positioning elements.  Is there anything special that needs to be done to center this component?  We've tried putting it in its own div.

We could recreate it on our own, but all of the code for validation is there and we'd like to keep it working so well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap the component in a 'center' layout: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

It's under "custom layouts".

You'll need to copy the 'ux' folder under 'examples' into the main src folder in order for autoloading to work.